# What's the difference between [String!] and [String]!

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, option-type

I'm quite new to Swift and want to know the difference between `[String!]` and `[String]!`. Both are non optional? but `[String]!` indicates `nil` when uninitialized and `[String!]` does not?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`[String!]` is an array of implicitly unwrapped `String`s

`[String]!` is an implicitly unwrapped array of `String`s

That means that the first one can contain `nil` values but cannot itself be `nil`. The second one could itself be `nil` but its contents are always non-`nil`.

Answer (score 6):

### [String!]

This is an array of `Implicitly Unwrapped Strings`.

> It means that in each element of this array you could find a `String` or `nil`.

```
let list0: [String!] = ["Hello", nil, "world", nil]
```

### [String]!

This is an `Implicitly Unwrapped Array` that contains `String`.

> It means that in a variable declared like this you can find `nil` or an array where every element is a valid `String`.

```
let list1: [String]! = nil
let list2: [String]! = ["Hello", "world"]
```

Answer (score 2):

`[String!]` - this is a non optional array of optional `Strings`.
`[String]!` - this is a optional array of non optional `Strings`.